# On referencing power planes and return current paths

Tags: emc, signal-integrity

I recently worked on a 16-layer board design that contained only 2 ground planes, at the outer layers of the board, and several power planes (+1V1, +1V8, +3V0, +5V0) in the middle:

[image: board stackup image]

Since there are only 2 ground planes, a majority of the signal traces are referenced to power planes, which is bad, because switching noise will be coupled to these planes.

Please look at the following image and suppose we have a switching signal on layer IN_5H:
[image: switching signal]

Have I drawn the return currents correctly here? Am I correct in assuming that the only way the current induced on plane +5V0 can return to the source is through a stitching capacitor? It seems to me that the best position for this capacitor, to keep loop length short, is nearest the IC pin output. Is this correct?

Comment: 16 layers, geez. Are you made of money?

Comment: It probably could have been done in less layers. I inherited this design and the client doesn't seem to mind paying for it.

Comment: How much is it for how many boards, or can you not tell me?

Comment: I'll dig up the quote tomorrow.

Comment: Nice cross-sectional drawing - what tools was used ?

Comment: @rawbrawb - That's a screenshot from the layer stack-up editor in altium.

Comment: @ConnorWolf All I could find was the stackup spec sheet - no quote. Sorry.

Comment: You can play some other games, but it depends on a lot of things.  What is going on with the other end of IN_5H?  What kind of switching rates are your talking about?  Low current signal switching or high current?  How solid is the +5V0 plane?  Is the 3V or 5V plane expected to noisy?  One worse than the other?  Why and how are the two grounds separated?  Is the switching synchronous in the system?

Comment: Check out this article on Return Current Routing: https://embeetle.com/#blog/return-currents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you.  Current will be induced onto the +5V0 plane even though it is not the driver's power plane because it is capacitively coupled to the signal traces.

Regarding the positive edge of the pulses:

Current injected onto the +5V0 plane coming from the signal traces as this capacitance gets discharged will go to ground via its bypass capacitors, and then it needs to go back to the +3V0 plane via the +3V0 caps and into the driver's power input, completing the circuit.

Having bypass capacitors sprinkled about on both planes allows the current jump to ground and from there to +3V0 (which is also the best return path you have) quickly.

Bypass capacitors near the driver (on the +3V0 plane) are very important anyway because they constitute the local energy storage to charge the transmission line, and they minimize the loop and inductance, and like you say, are how the current injected onto the +5V0 goes back to the source (but you can have others that are not necessarily next to the driver).

The negative edges of the pulses should follow a similar logic.